# Solving nonlinear first order PDE via Charpit's method

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given 1st order nonlinear PDE, in the form of:
$$
F = p - \frac{1}{4}q^2 - y^2 = 0
\space \space \text{with} \space x=x_0(s), y=y_0(s), u=u_0(s), p= p_0(s), q= q_0(s)
\\ (p=u_x,q=u_y)  
$$
Via Charpit's method, we can get:
$$
\frac{dx}{d\tau} = 1,\quad\frac{dy}{d\tau}=-\frac{1}{2}q,\quad\frac{dp}{d\tau}=0,\quad\frac{dq}{d\tau}=2y,\quad\frac{du}{d\tau}=p-\frac{1}{2}q^2
$$
This can be solved as
$$x=\tau +x_0(s),\quad p=p_0(s),\quad u=\frac{1}{2}qy+(\frac{1}{2}q_0(s)y_0(s)-u_0(s))$$
Does anyone know how to get the parameteric form of $u$, $q$ and $y$?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$
\frac{d^2y}{d\tau^2}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{dq}{d\tau}=-y \implies y(\tau)=A\cos\tau+B\sin\tau, \tag{1}
$$
hence
$$
q(\tau)=-2\frac{dy}{d\tau}=2A\sin\tau-2B\cos\tau. \tag{2}
$$
Using the initial conditions $y(0)=y_0(s)$, $q(0)=q_0(s)$ to determine $A$ and $B$, we obtain
\begin{align}
y(\tau)&=y_0(s)\cos\tau-\frac{1}{2}q_0(s)\sin\tau, \tag{3a}\\
q(\tau)&=q_0(s)\cos\tau+2y_0(s)\sin\tau. \tag{3b}
\end{align}
To obtain $u(\tau)$, solve
$$
\frac{du}{d\tau}=p-\frac{1}{2}q^2, \qquad u(0)=u_0(s), \tag{4}
$$ with $p=p_0(s)$ and $q$ given by Eq. $(3b)$.